# Proving the ASA, SAS congruence of triangles in absolute geometry.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, congruences-geometry

I am asked to prove the SAS (side-angle-side) and ASA(angle-side-angle) congruence of triangles in absolute geometry ( the geometry based in the axiom system of Euclides with the parallel postulate removed).

How do I even prove two triangles are congruent without using the SAS, ASA or SSS criteria? Do I have to see the congruence between any of sides or angles of the two triangles?

Comment: This depends on exactly what your axioms are.  For instance, if you are using Hilbert's axioms, then SAS itself is one of the axioms.

Comment: @EricWofsey Well, not exactly one of the axioms, but nearly so.

Comment: @OP can you clarify which axiom system you are using?